# Call component through function React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm developing a `component` to publish it in `npm`, but I'd like to call my component using a `method` instead of a tag.

Example:

**myComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

export const showComponent = () => {
    // this would be the function that I user to call my component down
}

const myComponent = (props) => {
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>Oi</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { showComponent } from 'my-component'

const App = () => {
    return(
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => showComponent()}>
                <Text>Home</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}

export defaul App
```

the idea is that when calling the `showComponent` function I show my component, and when I call, for example, the `hide` function, I close my component.

Comment: Why are you not passing a prop to your component to hide/show it ?

Comment: I would like to call it within the `redux action`, so I thought of the` method` (just like `nativebase` does with `Toast`), it will be a `popup component`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a single class export:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isOpen: false,
  };

  open = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: true });
  };

  close = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: true });
  };

  render() {
    const { isOpen } = this.state;

    return !isOpen ? null : (
      <View>
        <Text>Oi</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And you use it like so:

```
<MyComponent ref={(x) => this.myComponent = x)} />
```

And you open it like so:

```
this.myComponent.open();
```

Comment: Perfect, i think that this that i wanted. i gonna go try.

Answer (score 0):

I see in a comment above you want to call the component with a redux action, so you should call your redux action in that on click, but the component you want to show/hide needs to be linked to a redux state variable. Then in your jsx you'd have:

```
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => showComponent()}>
                <Text>Home</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            {reduxBoolean && <MyComponent />}
        </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text} from 'react-native'
const example = (props) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

// props

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text} from 'react-native'

const examples = () => {
    return(
        <View>
            <Text><example/></Text>
        </View>    
    )
}
```

and print is : Hello